# Format custom date order field

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, date

I have created a custom field when submitting an order called: Delivery Date.

I want to display this in my transactional e-mail that is being sent after placing the order.

When i code it like this:

```
"var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')":"Order Created At (datetime)",
"var order.getDeliveryDate()":"Delivery Date",
```

It will display the delivery date like 2015/03/31

the Order Created At, will display it like: 31/03/2015.

I have tried adding `'long'` but that doesn't work. How can i format this custom date like the created at date?

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` and add your own custom method like the one for `getCreatedAtFormated()`. I am assuming you can create an extension or look up how to do that, your new method should look something like this:

```
class My_Sales_Model_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order
{
    public function getDeliveryDateFormated($format)
    {
        return Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($this->getDeliveryDate(), $format, true);
    }
}
```

You can then call it in your template just like the other one:

```
var order.getDeliveryDateFormated('long')
```